# Nvidia Control Panel Blank

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-settings

All of a sudden Nvida's control panel is almost blank. I have 2 GTX 770s in SLI and the only new graphical things are changing digital vibrance (kicking up saturation) and moving to 4K (Samsung U28D590D) But this was all many restarts and graphic driver updates ago. I have the latest and greatest everything, and I have seen a while screen appear before. Lastly, I am the OEM builder. If you know how to fix this or have any ideas, that would be wonderful. Thanks

[image: Control Panel]

Comment: Is the user an `Administrator` or an `User`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of available drivers for your setup. I just setup an SLI 450 GTS PC last night. The Nvidia control panel seems to have more features than what your experiencing...

http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us

```
GeForce Game Ready Driver WHQL  344.75  November 18, 2014
GeForce Game Ready Driver WHQL  344.65  November 10, 2014
GeForce Game Ready Driver WHQL  344.60  November 4, 2014
GeForce Game Ready Driver WHQL  344.48  October 22, 2014
GeForce Game Ready Driver WHQL  344.11  September 18, 2014
GeForce 340.52 Driver WHQL  340.52  July 29, 2014
GeForce 340.43 Driver BETA  340.43  June 17, 2014
GeForce 337.88 Driver WHQL  337.88  May 26, 2014
GeForce 337.50 Driver BETA  337.50  April 7, 2014
GeForce 335.23 Driver  WHQL 335.23  March 10, 2014
GeForce 334.89 Driver WHQL  334.89  February 18, 2014
GeForce 334.67 Beta Driver  BETA    334.67  January 27, 2014
GeForce 332.21 Driver WHQL  332.21  January 7, 2014
GeForce R331 Game Ready Driver BETA 331.93  November 27, 2013
GeForce R331 Game Ready Driver WHQL 331.82  November 19, 2013
GeForce R331 Game Ready Driver WHQL 331.65  November 7, 2013
GeForce R331 Game Ready Driver WHQL 331.58  October 21, 2013
GeForce 331.40 Driver BETA  331.40  September 30, 2013
GeForce 327.23 Driver WHQL  327.23  September 19, 2013
GeForce 326.80 Driver BETA  326.80  August 20, 2013
```

Maybe uninstall everything nvidia and try an old version?

Comment: Nice neat columns of driver versions and dates seemed to have been melded together in a mess there....word wrap ? sorry

Comment: Here is a partial explanantion from Nvidia...may not be your exact situation though. http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13/~/missing-nvidia-control-panel-pages